# A common user model , controller ,authentication and ability for multiple Rails apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan, cas

I have developed two rails applications app1 and app2, they have their own user controller and model and own ability.rb file and own devise gem. I want all of them share a common user controller and user model and ability.rb file so that anyone irrespective of the application goes through the same authentication system.

In this context I have read the post [Rails: Devise Authentication from an ActiveResource call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503156/rails-devise-authentication-from-an-activeresource-call) and [How to add authentication before filter to a rails 3 apps with devise for user sign up and sign in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073505/how-to-add-authentication-before-filter-to-a-rails-3-apps-with-devise-for-user-s?rq=1). But I am sorry, I could not figure out how to modify their individual `routes.rb` file so that all the authentication requests redirected to it and I would like to know if I have to make another application for only management of user for that purpose.

Comment: you'd need to just do the same things (install gems, set up routes, etc) in both apps. I don't think you can share routes(or anything else) between applications

Answer (score 0):

You might use **omniauth** gem to provide one application to manage its users through the second one (like a Facebook connect, for example). This app's sign in action would just be a redirect to the second one's sign in page.
In this case, however, you would have 2 different user tables, which might need synchronization, but for just a simple authentication that could work.

Comment: With this approach you can't. And if your applications store other custom data about users more than email and password you should have 2 separate tables for them.

Comment: Then is there any other solution for the same where I can use my existing single user table?